# How to make the "Ship to different address" default? (the radio button) in STEP 1 of the CHECKOUT (under BILLING INFORMATION)

Tags: layout-update

It seems that many of our customers are not smart enough to figure this out so we have to make the "Ship to different address" option default (checked - the radio button). This is in STEP 1 of the Checkout (1 BILLING INFORMATION)

What is the best way to do that? Thanks for any suggestions! :-*

---

Edited on June 1st, 2018:

I have implemented the solution below and it worked great.

Now, however, all of sudden - it reverts back to "Ship to this address" again. I went into the **billing.phtml** file in

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage
```

and the code is still the correct one (the changed one). **Would anyone know why this just stopped working all of a sudden by itself?** *(the file was not overwritten)*

Comment: you can change the code in persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml to make the option checked by default

Comment: Thank you saravanavelu! you are correct - I changed checked = false to checked = true and checked = true to checked = false and that did the trick!

Comment: @saravanavelu I made this change and it worked. Then, all of sudden - it reverts back to "Ship to this address" again. I went into the billing.phtml file in '/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage and the code is still the correct one (the changed one). Would anyone know why this just stopped working all of a sudden by itself? (the file was not overwritten)

Answer (score 2):

Just as saravanavelu says:

Edit '**billing.phtml**' in

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage

Change this:

```
<li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
        </li>
```

TO THIS:

```
<li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
        </li>
```